# R "forestplot" package: Error message when using "group_by" ! missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, r-forestplot, forest-plots

I'm using the forestplot package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forestplot/vignettes/forestplot.html) for an observational cohort study. I am trying to show the forestplot of the hazard ratios for each outcome with 95%CI and the numbers as text next to the graph. I have managed to make individual results for each group using the below code:

```
library(forestplot)
library(dplyr)

AAA_smoker_HR_2 <- tibble::tibble(mean  = c(1.23, 0.90, 0.86),
                            lower = c(0.87, 0.87, 0.81),
                            upper = c(1.73, 0.94, 0.92),
                            var = c("In-Hospital Mortality",
                                    "Length of Hospital Stay",
                                    "Length of ITU Stay"),
                            HR = c("1.23 (0.87-1.73)", "0.90 (0.87-0.94)", "0.86 (0.81-0.92)"))

AAA_smoker_HR_2 |>
  forestplot(labeltext = c(var, HR),
             fn.ci_norm = fpDrawDiamondCI,
             zero = 1,
             clip = c(0.0, 2.0),
             boxsize = 0.18,
             vertices = TRUE,
             ci.vertices.height = 0.05,
             lineheight = "lines",
             xlab = "Hazard Ratio (HR)",
             xticks = c(0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0)
             ) |>
  fp_add_lines() |> 
  fp_set_style(box = "black",
               line = "black",
               hrz_lines = "#999999",
               txt_gp = fpTxtGp(ticks=gpar(cex=0.75),
                              label=gpar(cex=0.9),
                              xlab=gpar(cex=0.9))) |> 
  fp_add_header(var = c("", "Variable"),
                HR = c("", "HR (95% CI)")) |>
  fp_decorate_graph(graph.pos = 2)
```

[This graph is generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7Z1z.png)

I have 3 subgroups in total (All, OSR, and EVAR) and created respective data frames for each. I am now trying to create a forestplot that will include all three subgroups as per Max Gordon's instructions and using dplyr to merge into one data frame. The code is below:

```
OSR_smoker_HR_2 <- tibble::tibble(mean  = c(1.18, 1.00, 0.96),
                            lower = c(0.87, 0.97, 0.91),
                            upper = c(1.60, 1.04, 1.01),
                            var = c("In-Hospital Mortality",
                                    "Length of Hospital Stay",
                                    "Length of ITU Stay"),
                            HR = c("1.18 (0.87-1.60)", "1.00 (0.97-1.04)", "0.96 (0.91-1.01)"))

EVAR_smoker_HR_2 <- tibble::tibble(mean  = c(1.22, 0.98, 0.92),
                            lower = c(0.82, 0.91, 0.85),
                            upper = c(1.82, 1.04, 0.99),
                            var = c("In-Hospital Mortality",
                                    "Length of Hospital Stay",
                                    "Length of ITU Stay"),
                            HR = c("1.22 (0.82-1.82)", "0.98 (0.91-1.04)", "0.92 (0.85-0.99)"))

AAA_J_smoker_HR <- bind_rows(lst(AAA_smoker_HR_2, OSR_smoker_HR_2, EVAR_smoker_HR_2), .id = 'study')

AAA_J_smoker_HR <- AAA_J_smoker_HR %>%
  mutate(study = case_when(
    study == "AAA_smoker_HR_2" ~ "All",
    study == "OSR_smoker_HR_2" ~ "OSR",
    study == "EVAR_smoker_HR_2" ~ "EVAR"
  ))

AAA_J_smoker_HR |>
  group_by(study) |>
  forestplot(labeltext = c(var, HR),
             fn.ci_norm = c(fpDrawDiamondCI, fpDrawNormalCI, fpDrawCircleCI),
             zero = 1,
             clip = c(0.0, 3.0),
             boxsize = 0.18,
             vertices = TRUE,
             ci.vertices.height = 0.05,
             lineheight = "lines",
             xlab = "Hazard Ratio (HR)",
             xticks = c(0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 3.0)
             ) |>
  fp_add_lines() |> 
  fp_set_style(box = c("black","blue","darkred"),
               line = "black",
               hrz_lines = "#999999",
               txt_gp = fpTxtGp(ticks=gpar(cex=0.75),
                              label=gpar(cex=0.9),
                              xlab=gpar(cex=0.9))|> lapply(function(x) gpar(fill = x, col = "#555555")),
               default = gpar(vertices=TRUE)) |> 
  fp_add_header(var = c("", "Variable"),
                HR = c("", "HR (95% CI)")) |>
  fp_decorate_graph(graph.pos = 2)
```

However, I get the error message:

```
Error in `dplyr::mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `data = lapply(...)`.
ℹ In group 1: `.fp_groups = "All"`.
Caused by error in `if (df$.fp_labels[i] != all_labels[i]) ...`:
! missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
Backtrace:
  1. forestplot::fp_decorate_graph(...)
 18. base::lapply(...)
 19. forestplot (local) FUN(X[[i]], ...)
```

When I use filter(group == "OSR") and without lapply the code still works to generate a single graph, but not when using group_by().

Any help at all is much appreciated!!

I'm not sure if it's the dataframe formatting causing an issue as there are no NA values... and picking out the groups individually works with the code. So I'm at a loss!

Comment: For being new to SO, you've got a great start to asking questions with the necessary information. There is a bit missing, unfortunately. The second half of your question, with the non-working plot, is not reproducible. I tried to follow the process with my own data but didn't run into any problems. Could you provide a sample of `OSR_smoker_HR_2` and `EVAR_smoker_HR_2`? You can use `dput(head(dataToSample))`, just make sure your data samples reproduce the error.

Comment: @Kat: Apologies, I have added some sample data for the purpose of the code for the other two data frames.

Comment: Right now you're trying to group the data by `study`, then group the labels by `var` and `HR`,  however, you've got unique values in `HR`, so you can't group the data that way. You could make a field like high, med, low, or a threshold...

Comment: Okay, so I did think [labeltext] had something to do with it, as set in the example on the CRAN website [labeltext] is not used when group_by() is used; but when I remove this line the error states that the function can't be run as "! Column `labeltext` doesn't exist." - which leads me to believe it is something to do with the formatting of my dataframe?

Comment: I ran by the same problem. Was this issue ever resolved?